# Create `suffixes` Function on List

Tags: haskell, reinventing-the-wheel

I wrote the following `suffixes` function. Given a list, it returns the list + all sub-lists.

> suffixes [1,2,3,4] == [[1,2,3,4], [2,3,4], [3,4], [4], []]

Please critique my implementation.

```
suffixes :: [a] -> [[a]]
suffixes []         = [] : []
suffixes xxs@(_:xs) = xxs : suffixes xs
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks good to me. The only thing I would change is

> ```
> suffixes [] = [] : []
> ```

to

```
suffixes [] = [[]]
```

as it's a bit more readable.

When re-inventing functions, it can be instructive to look up their definition using [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=tails). Following the links, we find this definition in [`Data.List`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/src/Data-List.html#tails):

```
tails                   :: [a] -> [[a]]
tails xs                =  xs : case xs of
                                  []      -> []
                                  _ : xs' -> tails xs'
```

Comment: Thank you for your continued help on most/all of my recent questions.

Comment: @KevinMeredith my pleasure. I thoroughly enjoyed the previous one (Streams) in particular :)